# Clearing the background color of rows that are dropped into a QTableView

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, background-color, qtableview

I have two QTableViews with different QStandardItemModels that are placed next to each other on my layout. One of the tableviews accepts drops from the other and that has been working well so far.
This is how the model is set up:

```
    self.auto_queue_model = QStandardItemModel()
    self.auto_queue.setModel(self.auto_queue_model)
```

The table rows that are dropped into the tableview come with two different background colors. I am having some trouble implementing a way for those background colors to be deleted or reset once the rows are dropped to the second tablewidget.

I have tried installing an event filter like so:

self.auto_queue.installEventFilter(self)

```
def eventFilter(self, source, event):
   if source.objectName() == 'auto_queue':
        if event.type() == QEvent.Drop:
            for row in range(0, self.auto_queue_model.rowCount()):
                item = self.auto_queue_model.item(row, 0)
                if item:
                    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(70, 70, 70))

    return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

But I can not get PyQt to recognize the event.type() as QEvent.Drop even though it is in the documentation
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html

I have also tried connecting a signal to a function like so:

self.auto_queue_model.rowsInserted.connect(self.resetAutoQueueColors)

```
def resetAutoQueueColors(self, index, column, row):
    print(column,row, self.auto_queue_model.rowCount())
    for row in range(0, self.auto_queue_model.rowCount()):
        item = self.auto_queue_model.item(row, 0)
        if item:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(70, 70, 70))
```

I have tried both changing the background of the dropped row(s) that are received by the resetAutoQueueColors function individually and looping over all rows like in the sample above. The problem seems to be that the signal is fired before the rows are actually added to the model. It then changes the background of all rows except for the ones I have dropped. The new rows are added to the rowCount(), but the item at that index location returns None at the time of the execution of the function.

i have also tried to subclass the QTableView and emitting a signal, but have been unsuccessful.

Also, I am wondering if there is a way to reset the background color instead of setting it explicitly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use a subclass of QStandardItemModel for the source, override [`itemData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemData), get the result of the base implementation (which is a dictionary with `role:value` pairs), remove the `BackgroundRole` key if it exists and return it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me again musicamante!
I have not used an override in a subclass before so I had to look this up. 
Would it be done like this?

`class AutoQueueModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QStandardItemModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def superIdemData(self):
        dict = super().itemData()
        [item.remove('BackgroundRole') for item in dict if 'BackgroundRole' in item]
        return


self.auto_queue_model = AutoQueueModel()
self.auto_queue.setModel(self.auto_queue_model)`

Comment: I have tried the above with 
´self.auto_queue_model.rowsInserted.connect(self.auto_queue_model.superIdemData)´
and am running into some errors. Will try to resolve.

Comment: I've resolved the errors by passing in the index, but now i am getting an empty dict as a return value. not sure why.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to do some research about subclassing. Overriding means creating a method that has the same name of an existing one and *altering* its behavior, so you have to create a method called `itemData` and return the appropriate value that is expected from it (in this case, a dictionary based on the default implementation).

Comment: Thank you. I will look into those concepts.